# Cannot send a keystroke to a program with C# - tried so many different things

Tags: c#, input, keyboard

Hello I'm trying to send a keystroke to a streaming program to change scenes with a hot key and I just can't figure out why it's not working. I've tried a few different methods: sendkeys, keybd_event, and postmessage but I can't get it to work at all. It also finds the size of the rectangle and such but I don't think that's relevant to my issue because that all seems to work fine.

It seems to have no problem finding the correct virtual key code so I'm just not sure what to do. I've googled just about everywhere! I'll admit I'm not much of a C# programmer but I can usually stumble through these things without too much hassle. Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

EDIT: Changed flags to 0 and 2 for keydown and keyup respectively.

EDIT: The first keystroke seems to work when I comment out the switchtothiswindow but the subsequent keystrokes only work when alt-tabbed out of the game. so I don't know what to do here.

```
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte vk, byte scan, int flags, int extrainfo);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool fAltTab);

    public const ushort WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0000;
    public const ushort WM_KEYUP = 0x0002;

        //virtual key code enum
    public enum KeyCodes : byte
    {
    F1 = 0x70,
    F2 = 0x71,
    F3 = 0x72,
    F4 = 0x73,
    F5 = 0x74,
    F6 = 0x75,
    F7 = 0x76,
    F8 = 0x77,
    F9 = 0x78,
    F10 = 0x79,
    F11 = 0x7A,
    F12 = 0x7B,
    f1 = 0x70,
    f2 = 0x71,
    f3 = 0x72,
    f4 = 0x73,
    f5 = 0x74,
    f6 = 0x75,
    f7 = 0x76,
    f8 = 0x77,
    f9 = 0x78,
    f10 = 0x79,
    f11 = 0x7A,
    f12 = 0x7B,
    }

    //enum parse
    public byte FindKeyCode (string fkey)
    {
        return (byte)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCodes), fkey);

    }

    //press the keys
    public static void PressKeys(byte key)
    {
        SwitchToThisWindow(obsHandle, true);
        keybd_event(key, Convert.ToByte(MapVirtualKey(key, 0)), WM_KEYDOWN, 0);
        keybd_event(key, Convert.ToByte(MapVirtualKey(key, 0)), WM_KEYUP, 0);
        SwitchToThisWindow(wHandle, true);
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Scene1Key = FindKeyCode(textBox1.Text);


    }

    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Scene2Key = FindKeyCode(textBox2.Text);

    }
```

Comment: Your *flags* argument to keybd_event() is wrong, it doesn't take a Windows message number.  Pass 0 for keydown, 2 for keyup.

Comment: Thanks, I changed that. It still doesn't want to work but that's one thing off the list

Comment: Not sure if this pertains to your problem, but PostMessage has this to say: "Starting with Windows Vista, message posting is subject to UIPI. The thread of a process can post messages only to message queues of threads in processes of lesser or equal integrity level."  I've occasionally seen some things restricted from CLI programs.  If you can, I'd have a go at it from native code first, and if you can get _that_ to work, then worry about how to make C# do it.